# Implementing `continue;` keywords in jQuery's `each();` method

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Imagine that I want to loop over a list of jQuery objects, and for each of them execute some functions. However, if in some place, a criteria is not met, then I simply want to `continue;` to other objects. The simple pseudo-code might be something like:

```
$('#element').each(function(){
    // some code here
    if (!$(this).is('.included')) {
       continue; // This keyword of course, doesn't work here
    }
    // more code here, which won't get executed for some elements
});
```

I wan to achieve the same effect as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 ) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

I know that I can `return false;` somewhere inside `each();` method, to completely break the looping. But I don't want to break looping. I only want to skip some elements. I also know that I can use `if-else` blocks to skip elements, but is there a more neat way to do this?

Comment: Returning non-false value would do it, however this is not explicitly documented - (you can guess this from $.each() docs which, hopefuly, has similar handling)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simply use `return;` instead of `continue;` (not `return false;`).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/each/) doesn't point this out explicitly (though the doco for the [generic iterator `each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) does mention it).

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `.each` jQuery function, you're passing a function to be executed for each value in the Array. The `continue` keyword is not implied in functions, but only in a direct loop. The reason jQuery breaks when you return a false value is because of this line in the jQuery libary:

```
if ( callback.apply( object[ name ], args ) === false ) {
  break;
}
```

jQuery purposely exits the loop when the executed function returns false. It would be common sense to add this, right? Since it uses `===` you can return anything that isn't directly equal to `false`, including `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `true`, or anything. As long as it doesn't equal `false`, the loop will continue.

```
$.each([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], function(i) {
  if(i > 5) { return false; } // if(i > 5) { break;    }
  if(i < 2) { return null;  } // if(i < 2) { continue; }
   console.log(i);
});
```

Your console would look like this:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Notice it didn't log 0 and 1. `i` was less than 2, so it continued without logging. Notice it didn't log 6, 7, 8, and 9. This is because when `i` became more than 5, it returned false.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery.each docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) says:

> " Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration. "

I usually do `return 'continue';` which is both readable and more self-explanatory than simple `return;`, `return true;` or `return 1;`

I've also encountered `return 'non-false';` which is quite funny in a geeky way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the need for the `continue` statement:

```
$('#element').each(function(){
    // some code here
    if( $(this).is('.included') ) {
        // more code here, which won't get executed for some elements
    }
});
```

This ought to do exactly the same, unless I'm missing something.